# If condition in rails - Few comments and one comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add this functionality to my rails app. This is the schema. I do not know how to write this code.

```
if
<%= @post.comments.count == 1 %>
puts 'Comment'

else
puts 'Comments'

For example:

1 Comment

5 Comments
```

Please help.

Comment: try using `pluralize` method `"Comment".pluralize(@post.comments)` or in your way you can try `@post.comments.count == 1 ? "Comment" : "Comment".pluralize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails has a built in helper which handles inflection (guessing how to pluralize english words).

```
pluralize(@post.comments.count, 'Comment')
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
 <% if @post.comments.count == 1 %>
     <%= Comment %>

 <% else %>
     <%= Comments %>
 <% end %>
```

Though you would be better off using the 'pluralize' method if this is indeed your use case.

```
 <%= pluralize(@post.comments.count, 'Comment') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Better solution** can be using `pluralize` method:

```
<%= pluralize(@post.comments.count, 'Comment') %>
```

In your way, ternary operator looks more suitable in your case.

```
<%= @post.comments.count == 1 ? 'Comment' : 'Comments' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the String method `pluralize` `"Comment".pluralize(@post.comments.count)`